# Database object in Template

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm really new to Symfony and Twig and I'm trying to get the information from the Database to the twig template or better say to the homepage.

In the Controller the code looks like this.

```
$product= $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
        ->find($productID); // $productID is given with the slug.
```

I'm returning this:

```
return $this->render("default/index.html.twig" ,array("data"=>$product))
```

In the twig template i use a foreach loop

```
{% for datas in data %}
  {{ datas.price }}

{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work.
I allready dumped the data and it looks like this.
[Dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6pOX.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this in ***Twig***:

```
{{ data.id }}
{{ data.name }}
{{ data.price }}
```

Because `data` is not object.

Comment: @DarkBee yes, when you have one object you can't do in `for loop`

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev

One question, if i had more entries and not only one it would work with my foreach loop, or do i misinterpret here something?

Comment: @Kira Yes, if you had more entries it work with `foreach`. For example:


               `$product= $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
        ->findAll();`